# NginxとPythonで構築されたWebシステムに連続でリクエストを送ると定期的にタイムアウトが発生する。

Tags: python, python3, django, nginx, uwsgi

Python Djangoである検査用のシステムを構築しています。
こちらのシステムでは、Djangoで構築したRestAPIに1秒間隔でPOSTリクエストが送られ、処理（0.3秒ほど）が完了したら結果を返すという単純な物ですが、リクエストを流すと100回に１回の割合で60秒間レスポンスが返ってこない事象が発生します。

また、通常時は約3.6KBのレスポンスが返ってきますが、この現象発生時は下記画像のようにレスポンス0で返ってきています。そのため、何らかの原因で処理が止まって60秒でタイムアウトしているのだと思うのですが、原因の特定ができなかったです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Djangoのrunserverではこの現象は発生せず、Nginx上で動かした時のみ発生するためNginxの設定が原因ではないかと思うのですが、調べても解決策が出てきませんでした。
もし同様の現象に心当たりがあれば教えていただきたいです。

**■構成**

- Django 3.0.3
- djangorestframework 3.11.0
- nginx 1.14.0
- uwsgi 2.0.19.1
- conda 4.8.2
- Python 3.7.6

**■環境**
Windows10のWSL（Ubuntu18.04.4 LTS）に構築

**■Nginx設定**

```
upstream django {
        server 127.0.0.1:8001;
}


server {
        listen          8000;
        server_name     127.0.0.1 localhost;
        charset         utf-8;
        root    /usr/share/nginx/html;
        
        location /static {
                alias /mnt/c/windows/system32/Python/XXXXX/static;
        }
        location / {
                uwsgi_pass      django;
                include     /mnt/c/windows/system32/Python/XXXXX/uwsgi_params;
                auth_basic      "認証";
                auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
        }
}
server_tokens off;
```

Comment: 60sでタイムアウトするのは、[uwsgi_connect_timeout](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.html#uwsgi_connect_timeout)のデフォルトが60sに設定されていることによるものかもしれません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。uwsgi_connect_timeoutの値を30sに設定したところレスポンスが30秒になったため、何らかの原因でタイムアウトが発生していると見て間違いないようです。